# document getelementid is returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting `document.getElementById("#toHide")` is null. How can solve this? how to convert this statement to jquery?

html:

```
<form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix" />
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
<img id="loadingImg" src="my image location" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
</div>
```

Java code creating JavaScript code in string buffer:

```
if(flag == false){
    flag = true;
    buffer.append("$('#toHide').doTimeout(1000, ");
    buffer.append("function() { ");
    buffer.append("$('#").append(component.getMarkupId()).append("').submit(");     
    buffer.append(");");
    buffer.append("$('#toHide').html('<img id=\"loadingImg\" src=\"../../img/load.gif\" style=\"margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\"/>'); ");
    buffer.append("});\n");
    }
    else{
       buffer.append("\n document.getElementById(\'#toHide\').style.display='none';\n");    
    }
    buffer.append("</script>");
```

2) i have declared flag=false at the global level. i am verifying for the first time for flag and allowing to enter if block shown above. But after this, image still display in next page. why? what changes i need to make?

Comment: It's *JavaScript*, not *Java*. Java is a completely different language. I've edited it in your question (someone else seems to have already removed the tag).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I think he's using Java to generate the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jQuery, try:

```
buffer.append("\n $(\'#toHide\').hide();\n");
```

instead of

```
buffer.append("\n document.getElementById(\'#toHide\').style.display='none';\n");
```

Comment: thanks, solved, one more question,but image displays in next page, i want to hide that image display. updated in main question. i hope i can edit and add another question.

Comment: How do you declare the `flag` variable? If the page refreshes, it also vanishes. Better if you put it as a session variable instead. (NB. Please post another question if it's not the original one. Mark a post as the answer if it is indeed so.)

Comment: static boolean flag = false. session will be problem, till the user exists, if condition willnot allow to go inside.

Comment: Yeah, it's a different issue altogether. Better if you post a new question about that, detailing the problem. I'm sure a better approach is out there. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

When you use `document.getElementById` you don't need the `#`

```
document.getElementById('toHide').style....
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` is not part of an id, so you should use:

```
document.getElementById('toHide')
```

.
As for jquery part:

```
$("#toHide").hide()
```

This time with `#`.

Comment: thanks, solved, one more question, updated in main question. i hope i can edit and add another question.